# Looping through a circular buffer in Chisel

Tags: chisel

Let's say I have implemented a circular buffer with a head and a tail. Is there an elegant scala-way of looping through this buffer starting from the head ending at the tail (and doing a possible wrap-around at the end)

```
class MyBuffer() extends Module 
{
  val data = Reg(Vec(NUM_ELEMENTS, Bool())
  val head = RegInit(0.U(NUM_ELEMENTS_W.W))
  val tail = RegInit(0.U(NUM_ELEMENTS_W.W))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your looping goal is. But consider the following code example (with a few details left out). This example exposes the contents of a RingBuffer as Vec view with ViewLength valid elements. I think this demonstrates a modestly elegant method for this definition of looping, the emitted hardware (or the view idea) may not be elegant. Let me know if is not quite the notion of looping you had in mind.

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.log2Ceil

/**
  * This ring buffer presents its current contents through view
  *
  * @param depth
  * @param bitWidth
  */
class RingBuffer(depth: Int, bitWidth: Int) extends MultiIOModule {
  /*
  You need a bunch of IO's here to push and pop and get full status
  */

  val view       = IO(Output(Vec(depth, UInt(bitWidth.W))))
  val viewLength = IO(Output(UInt(log2Ceil(depth).W)))

  val data = Reg(Vec(depth, Bool()))
  val head = RegInit(0.U(bitWidth.W))
  val tail = RegInit(0.U(bitWidth.W))

  /* Need some code here to push and pop elements */


  // this constructs a mapping between the indices between current head and tail
  // to the 0 to n indices of the view
  def mappedIndex(i: Int): UInt = {
    val out = Wire(UInt(log2Ceil(depth).W))
    when((i.U + head) <= depth.U) {
      out := i.U + head
    }.otherwise {
      out := (i.U + head) - depth.U
    }
    out
  }

  // This creates the complicated Mux structure to map betweem
  // the ring buffer elements and 0 to n style view
  view.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (viewElement, index) =>
    viewElement := data(mappedIndex(index))
  }

  // This presents the number of valid elements in the current view
  val difference = tail - head
  when((difference) < 0.U) {
    viewLength := (difference) + depth.U
  }.otherwise {
    viewLength := (difference)
  }
}
```